# Is there a list with all cookies that uses SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, cookie

I have to create a list with all cookies that SharePoint 2010 uses. I can't find this information on Microsoft site neither on google. I only find documents about how to create or use cookies and how to implement persistent cookies.

Does anybody if there is a list having the cookies information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can tell the cookies vary in name and scope depending on which feature issued them. Several features can use the same ones, but certain ones cannot be shared with other processes. Basically, it may be too complicated to list all possible cookies that SP uses (by name anyways), especially if you're using client integration features. Perhaps there is another way to accomplish what you are trying to do? What is the specific implementation here?

Answer (score 2):

This a very interesting question. Not sure if there is a table that lists all cookies SharePoint uses. But if this list does not exist - you can at least check it in browser yourself. Unfortunately, the cookies that SharePoint uses depends on the page you are currently at, but still.
I use Google Chrome's tools to check the cookies: 
[image]

Comment: This is a good solution for getting certain cookies but, are these all the cookies that sharepoint use? Instead of using Chrome this image show the cookies from Internet Explorer, http://ge.tt/76fNRrY/v/0

Comment: your links isn't working and also looks like a spam